# javascript: split sentance only by first space and insert into same list with. A functional approach

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I am not understanding how to use map working with a functional approach. I was not able to iterate through a list within a list.

I am trying to split the first string of multiple list of strings into only two strings and insert into back into a copy of the list. I tried using `.split(' ', 1)` but that would cut out the rest of the string. Here is my data:

```
const cars = [
    [ 'Ford 1968 mustang', 'blue'],
    [ 'Mercedez 2 door coupe', 'green'],
    [ 'Ford rusty escape', 'red'],
    [ 'Mercedez', 'black'],
    [ 'Ford expedition', 'purple'],
    [ 'mercedez helicopter with skies', 'orange']
]

    const split_string_by_space = one_string => 
        one_string.split(' ', 1);

    const iter_through_list_of_lists = outer_list => outer_list.map(inner_list => {
        inner_list.map(item => {
            split_string_by_space(item);
        })
    });

    const split_cars = iter_through_list_of_lists(cars);

    console.log(split_cars);
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
[ 'Ford', '1968 mustang', 'blue'],
[ 'Mercedez', '2 door coupe', 'green'],
[ 'Ford', 'rusty escape', 'red'],
[ 'Mercedez', '', 'black'],
[ 'Ford', 'expedition', 'purple'],
[ 'Mercedez', 'helicopter with skies', 'orange'],
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the result you're trying to achieve? The fourth array now has an uppercase `M` which appeared at the start of `mercedes` (not `ford` in fifth array), and an empty middle string.

Comment: And the last two grab the last color, while the first 3 grab the first color.

Comment: True, my mistake. I am splitting the question to two different sections because I am also trying to figure out how to convert the string into a list of split strings.

Comment: I see. Much appreciated @Blex

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want with the final string (the colors), but you can use the same technique to split that part.

See comments inline:

```js
const cars = [
    [ 'Ford 1968 mustang', 'blue'],
    [ 'Mercedez 2 door coupe', 'green'],
    [ 'ford rusty escape', 'red blue'],
    [ 'mercedez wide limo', 'black green'],
    [ 'ford expedition', 'red blue purple'],
    [ 'mercedez helicopter with skies', 'black green orange']
];

let results = cars.map(function(carString){
  let result = []; // Will hold array to return from the map iteration

  // Since each member of the initial array is another array,
  // we'll have to disect that array item:
  
  // Regular expression to split only on the first white space
  let strings = carString[0].split(/(?<=^\S+)\s/);
  
  // Add to the array to be returned:
  result.push(strings[0]);
  result.push(strings[1]);
  result.push(carString[1])
  return result;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott. Is there a way you'd recommend to not hard code the amount of pushes to result in the case of not knowing how many times it will need to be repeated. I've visualizing a conditional for type 'undefined'. Would that be the most efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Here is *one* way to do it:

```js
const cars = [
  ['Ford 1968 mustang', 'blue'],
  ['Mercedez 2 door coupe', 'green'],
  ['ford rusty escape', 'red'],
  ['mercedez', 'black'],
  ['ford expedition', 'purple'],
  ['mercedez helicopter with skies', 'orange']
];

const result = cars.map(
  ([first, second]) => {
    const splitFirst = first.split(/ (.+)/);
    return [
      splitFirst[0] || "",
      splitFirst[1] || "",
      second
    ]
  }
);

console.log(result);
/*
[
  ["Ford", "1968 mustang", "blue"],
  ["Mercedez", "2 door coupe", "green"],
  ["ford", "rusty escape", "red"],
  ["mercedez", "", "black"],
  ["ford", "expedition", "purple"],
  ["mercedez", "helicopter with skies", "orange"]
]
*/
```